# Extract root hive from Registry key path

Tags: .net, powershell, registry

Is there a registry equivalent of `[System.IO.path]::GetPathRoot($path)`? I want to recursively delete empty parent keys after deleting a specified key or property, so I want to walk back up the tree until I reach the root hive. And I would prefer not to just continue until an exception is thrown.

Comment: There are several ways to accomplish this. Include the relevant part of your code.

Comment: I guess what I am wondering is, is there a single method approach, just like with the example, but for the registry. What I decided to do instead is just check to see if the current key has a parent, and if so delete the current key and test the parent again. So `if ($parent.PSParentPath) {}` is the relevant conditional. But still curious if there IS a method that would find the root key or root hive, or if I need to roll my own. My Google-Fu suggests there is not, Microsoft never bothered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a specific function for this.

If you use the registry provider, you can also use the `PSDrive` property on the child items, which will give you information about the registry root:

```
(Get-Item "HKLM:\Software\Windows").PSDrive.Name
```

or

```
(Get-Item "HKLM:\Software\Windows").PSDrive.Root
```

Although for "regular" registry paths, it would still be as simple as

```
$root = $path.Split("\")[0]
```

As for your specific scenario, you could create a function like this:

```
function Remove-KeyIfEmpty {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Removes empty registry keys and optionally empty parent keys recursively.
#>
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    param (
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory,
            Position = 0,
            ValueFromPipeline,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName
        )]
        [Alias("PSPath")]
        [string]$Path,
        [switch]$Recurse
    )
    $key = Get-Item $Path
    if ($key.Property.Count -eq 0 -and $key.SubKeyCount -eq 0) {
        if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($key, "Remove-Item")) {
            Remove-Item $Path
            if ($Recurse -and $key.PSParentPath) {
                Remove-KeyIfEmpty $key.PSParentPath -Recurse
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
Remove-KeyIfEmpty "HKCU:\Software\Example\SubKey" -Recurse
```

It even supports common parameters, like the `-WhatIf`, `-Confirm`, `-Verbose` and `-ErrorAction` switches.